# how to receive files exported / shared on iOS with React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, export

Here is a screen shot from an app that export a file to other app.

I need to develop another app that receive this file directly. So, I want my app displayed here such that it can be selected as the export target.

How to achieve this with react native?

[image]

Comment: did you find solution ?

Comment: React-native-share-extension should work. However, it may not work if you are using react-native-navigation.

Comment: yeah, thanks. found this lib as well, but i can get my app to be displayed in the share menu of the target app i need. currently it only works with Safary's share menu.

Comment: You need to check the `NSExtensionActivationRule` of your share extension in its info.plist. It controls what type of data can be sent to this share extension. Perhaps you only allow `URL` to be exported to your share extension in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to expose native iOS to `FileProvider` (might be `DocumentProvider`) in order for your app to show up there. There seems to be an already made package for it, hopefully, it actually works and updated:

https://github.com/Artirigo/react-native-file-provider

Comment: @ykn121 This particular one is the android package. iOS and Android each handle this different natively but this particular functionality is usually referenced in the `FileProvider` for each OS. Hopefully, this leads you in the right direction.